# How to mean columns by values of another column?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to get the mean of a variable according to the group it belongs to.
Here is a reproducible example.

```
gender <- c("M","F","M","F")
vec1 <- c(1:4)
vec2 <- c(10:13)

df <- data.frame(vec1,vec2,gender)
variables <- names(df)
variables <- variables[-3]
#Wished result
mean1 <- c(mean(c(1,3)),mean(c(2,4)))
mean2 <- c(mean(c(10,12)),mean(c(11,13)))
gender <- c("M","F") 
result <- data.frame(gender,mean1,mean2)
```

How can I achieved such a result ? I would like to use the vector variables, containing the names of the variables to be summarized instead of writing each variables, as my dataset is quite big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(gender) %>% summarise(across(variables, list(mean = mean), .names = "{.fn}_{.col}"))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  gender mean_vec1 mean_vec2
  <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1 F              3        12
2 M              2        11
```

Comment: perfect, many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Using `aggregate`.

```
## formula notation
aggregate(cbind(vec1, vec2) ~ gender, df, FUN=mean)
#   gender vec1 vec2
# 1      F    3   12
# 2      M    2   11

## list notation
with(df, aggregate(list(mean=cbind(vec1, vec2)), list(gender=gender), mean))
#   gender mean.vec1 mean.vec2
# 1      F         3        12
# 2      M         2        11
```

If you get an error in the formula notation, it is because you have named another object `mean`. Use `rm(mean)` in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your swift answer. In my case, I have several variables, several X of whose I wish to extract the means. I have a vector containing the names of all these variables (namely "variables.vector" but I cannot use "aggregate(list(mean=variables.vector)". Do you know a workaround so I don't have to manually write each column name of which I wish to take the means ? Also, aggregate does not seems to keep the names of the variables but instead call them generically : "mean", "mean.1", "mean.2" etc. How can it be solved ? Thanks!

Comment: @JeandeLéry You may want to update your example to make it more similar to your real data.

Comment: I have edited the data.frame, is my request clearer ? Is there a more elegant way to use summarise for several variables than writing them all manually ?

Comment: @JeandeLéry Yes, see update pls.

Answer (score 1):

Use library dplyr

```
library(dplyr) 

gender <- c("M","F","M","F")
df <- data.frame(1:4,gender)

df %>% 
  group_by(gender) %>% 
  summarise(mean = X1.4 %>% mean())
```

Comment: Thakns for your answer, do you mind checking the update of my example ? I wish to summarize several variables using a vector containing the names of all these variables.